# Divide a ring into hash segments in node js?

Tags: node.js, range, md5

First, I am very new to nodejs. I want a function in nodejs that divides 2^128 into 'n' equal spaces and returns a list of length n. I should be able to use this list to determine in which range a given integer belongs. I expect the code to like the following:

```
function divideEqually(n){
/**
    code here
 **/
 return aListOfRanges;
 }

 function findIndex(hashDigest, aListOfRanges){
  /*
     inspect ranges and find index
  */
  return someIndexInList;

 }

 var list = divideEqually(15); //Returns a list of 15 equally spaced ranges
 var index = findIndex('d9729feb74992cc3482b350163a1a010', list) //Find index of a hex digest
```

How do I do this efficiently. The ranges should be computed lazily as 2^128 will be a huge number whereas 'n' is expected to be less than 20.